# How does Javascript filter out HTML tags while selecting words using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Notice：

> I'm not parsing HTML with regex, 
> here I only use it for plain text.  
> It's just that it goes beyond plain text and affects other html tags

Why does everyone say I should use `DOM` instead of regular expressions?
`DOM` obviously cannot select all words on a web page based on an array of words.

before I used `document.createTreeWalker()` to filter all text labels, it was too complicated and caused more errors.
So I want to do it with simple regex instead. Do you have a better way?

I think just 'filter out all text inside "<>"' with very simple regex syntax wouldn't it work? Why make it so complicated?

---

I need to select the words from the page based on an array of words, and wrap the words around 'span' tags (keeping the original HTML tags).

The problem with my code is that it replaces the attribute values of the HTML tag as well.

I need regular expressions to filter out HTML tags and select words.

I added a condition to the regular expression :(^<.*>), but it didn't work and broke my code.

How to do?

---

My code:

code Error: The `<div id="text">` should not be wrapped around the SPAN tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>span{background:#ccc;}</style>
<script>
//wrap span tags for all words
function add_span(word_array, element_) {
    for (let i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
        var reg_str = "([\\s.?,\"\';:!()\\[\\]{}<>\/])";  //  + "^(<.*>)"
        var reg = new RegExp(reg_str + "(" + word_array[i] + ")" + reg_str, 'g');
        element_ = element_.replace(reg, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
    }
    return element_;
}

window.onload = function(){
  console.log(document.body.innerText);
  // word array
  var word_array = ['is', 'test', 'testis', 'istest', 'text']

  var text_html = add_span(word_array, document.body.innerHTML);
  document.body.innerHTML = text_html;
  console.log(text_html);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text"><!--Error: The class attribute value here should not be wrapped around the SPAN tag-->
is test testis istest,
is[test]testis{istest}testis(istest)testis istest
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: regular expressions are the [wrong tool for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'm not parsing HTML with regex, here I only use it for plain text. It's just that it goes beyond plain text and affects other html tags

Comment: Yes, and that means you must parse HTML, for which regex is not suitable.

Comment: Why does everyone say I should use DOM instead of regular expressions? DOM obviously cannot select all words on a web page based on an array of words.

Comment: Sure it can. Why do you think it can't? With a DOM parser, you can walk along all the parts that are plain text and do whatever you want to happen to text and not to HTML constructs.

Comment: before I used `document.createTreeWalker()` to filter all text labels, it was too complicated and caused more errors. So I want to do it with simple regex instead. Do you have a better way?

Comment: No, `createTreeWalker` is best practice.

Comment: `document.createTreeWalker()` being complicated is probably using a "normal" sample of HTML, rather than trying to learn on a smaller, simpler document to gain experience first it's definitely not "easy," but it *is* the better way to approach the problem. Regular expressions require a mostly regular language rather than HTML with its inconsistencies and edge-cases.

Comment: I think just 'filter out all text inside "<>"' with very simple regex syntax wouldn't it work? Why make it so complicated?

Comment: Provide me that simple regex, and I'll provide you HTML for which it fails... *always*.

Comment: example filter:`(^<.*>)`

Comment: Sorry, but this is really a bad attempt. `^` will match the start of the input (or the line if you add the `m` modifier), the `.*` part will match more than just one tag... Seems you think `^`  is a NOT operation here (it isn't). Moreover, I was not suggesting we do a ping pong here of try and counter example. If you want, try really hard and send me an email (see my profile) with your very best attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fun with this one and learned a few things too. You could replace the traversal implementation with [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) if you'd like. I added a nested `div#text2` to demonstrate how it works with arbitrary tree depth. I tried to keep the same general approach you were using, but needed to make some modifications to the regex and add tree traversal. Hope this helps!

```js
function traverse(tree) {
  const queue = [tree];

  while (queue.length) {
    const node = queue.shift();

    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      const textContent = node.textContent.trim();
      if (textContent) {
        const textContentWithSpans = textContent
        .replaceAll(/\b(is|test|testis|istest|text)\b/g, '<span>$&</span>');
          
        const template = document.createElement('template');
        template.innerHTML = textContentWithSpans;

        const fragment = template.content;
        
        node.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, node);
      }
    }
    
    for (let child of node.childNodes) {
      queue.push(child);
    }
  }
}

traverse(document.getElementById('demo-wrapper'));
```

```html
<div id="demo-wrapper">
  <div id="text">
  is test testis istest,
  is[test]testis{istest}testis(istest)testis istest
    <div id="text2">
    foo bar test istest
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, after reading everyone's answers, I have decided to abandon regular expressions and use the previous `document.createTreeWalker()` technique to accomplish my needs.I will make you the final answer